# Kendo Grid: Getting Dates to Format Correctly with Row Templates

Tags: date, formatting, kendo-grid

On a Kendo UI grid I am trying to get my dates to show up in a nicer format than what it's currently giving me.  I do not want to parse these dates to strings, so that I will be able to use more user-friendly filtering options.

This is what I currently have as part of the row template:

```
 <td>#: date_scheduled #</td>
```

In my table, what I'm getting is "Mon Jul 01 2013 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)", when I would much prefer to see "7/1/2013".

Is there any way, at the row template method, that this can be done?  I've done a lot of research already and found similar questions, but no answer which seems to exactly match this question.

Thank you very much in advance for your help!

---Edited---

Just figured this out:  It should be 
`<td>#=kendo.toString(date_scheduled, "d") #</td>`

Thanks!

Comment: I'm confused, you say you *don't* want to "parse these dates to strings".  But then you ask how to display a better string?  I think you meant "format" instead of "parse", but I still can't understand what you mean.

Comment: Are you just looking for `kendo.toString`? http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/framework/globalization/dateformatting

Comment: Hi Matt, sorry if I'm unclear on this.  While what I want LOOKS like a string, of course, but I want to be sortable and --particularly-- filterable as a date.  Kendo UI grids give different options for filtering whether the data in the column is identified as a string or as a date: strings give options like "Starts with" and "Ends with" while date filters give options "Before" and "After", which I think users would find much easier to deal with.  Does this make more sense?

Comment: Thanks Matt Johnson, I had been to that page before but didn't connect it with using the Kendo pound(#=  and #:) templating.  I put the answer I was looking for in the edit above. Have a great one, and I appreciate the help!

Comment: Please instead of editing your question, just go ahead and supply an answer.  It's ok to answer your own question.